# Storing strings in a vector causes error

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm trying to store strings that I read from a file in a std::vector but I'm getting a weird error...

So I have the container:

```
std::vector<std::string> m_Strings;
```

Then I read the string from a stream:

```
ifstream inStream;
char word[100];
//[...]
inStream >> word;
m_Strings.push_back(word);
```

Even though the vector is empty, when I insert the first string the vector resizes to hold 8 strings, the string at index 0 containing random characters, at index 1 containing the correct word, and the other indices containing invalid pointers...

Any idea of what might cause this?

EDIT: In this case I'm reading the string "DIRECTIONAL_LIGHT" so it fits in the `char word[100]`

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Did you read more than 99 characters into `word`?

Comment: Any reason for reading chars instead of a string?

Comment: This is really susceptible to buffer overflows... That might be the problem.

Comment: Taking the hints from stark and dgnorton: let's see if we can kill two birds with one stone: do things work better if you change `char word[100];` to `std::string word;`?

Comment: yes it works correctly using std::string word...  thanks

Comment: Voting to close as too localized. Apparently the OP was testing his 99-char buffer with input over 99 chars. Brilliant.

Comment: ildjarn: Thats not true I was reading the string "DIRECTIONAL_LIGHT" which is far from 99 characters...

Comment: Just tried it with "DIRECTIONAL_LIGHT" and it worked for me (GCC 4.7.0, OSX)

Comment: @Tiago : That makes zero sense, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just changed `char word[100];` to `std::string word;` and the error disappeared.

Comment: In general, when the length of a string is not *definitely* known, you should use `std::string` or `malloc` or `new` so that unknowing users don't cause buffer overflows and so that malicious users can't.